# Importing data and keeping ids and relationships

Tags: php, cakephp, foreign-key-relationship

I am working on cleaning up a mess that another programmer started.  The created 2 identical databases for different locations but that obviously caused major issues.  They are using cakePHP and there are quite a few relationships.  I am pretty sure I will have to write a script to import that data from on DB to the other and keep all the relationships but was wondering if there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which database are you using? How big are the databases in terms of records?

**Idea #1**

What about a tool like RedGate's SQL Data Compare?  It compares the data between two databases and lets you synchronize them.

I used to use this tool all the time to synchronize changes between different production db's and it works like a dream.  RedGate's sql tools are top notch (not affiliated with them at all).

SQL Data Compare: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_data_compare/index.htm

**Idea #2**

You'll have to disable foreign key constraints to import all the data if there are lots of relationships.  Once you do that you can import the data one table at a time.  If you are using a database like mysql, use mysqldump to create the sql inserts.  The process of creating a script is mostly automated for you.  Still grunt work though.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a cakePHP so there are no real FK constraints in the database.  But I will take a look at RedGate.